# Behaviour of NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, nan, coercion, type-coercion

In this example the function `sanitise()`

returns `NaN` value if the passed value is not a number

else it would return the passed value.

```
Case1: function sanitise(x) { if (isNaN(x)) { return NaN; } return x; } console.log(sanitise(1)); // expected output: "1" console.log(sanitise('NotANumber')); // expected output: NaN
```

So if this function filters and outputs the same  **if the argument is
only a number** and not string or any other type. I see an exception in
case 2.

In Case 2, I am passing a variable containing string (anything which is
in quotes). To confirm the same i have even consoled type of the value
contained in the variable "input".

```
Case2: function sanitise(x) { if (isNaN(x)) { return NaN; } return x; } var input = '1'; console.log(typeof input); console.log(sanitise(input)); // expected output: NaN // But actual output: 1 console.log(sanitise('NotANumber')); // expected output: NaN
```

So now the argument passed is a string but still**the string is being
treated as a number**. Kindly help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: `isNaN` will evaluate if the _string number_ is an actual number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description

Comment: Use this: `Number.isNaN()` instead after you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description

Answer (score 1):

You stumbled upon the confusing special-case behaviour of `isNaN()`. [Check the documentation for more details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

But, in short, how NaN works in this special case is defined by this line in the documentation -

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the
>   value is first coerced to a Number

So, in your case the string '1' is first coerced to a number and then checked. That's why you're getting the "unexpected" behaviour.
If you want to strictly check against the type, you can check by using `typeof value !== 'number'`

Comment: typeof is not necessary. your answer indicates exactly why `Number.isNaN()` was added. The OP should simply use the correct version of the function.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please run and try to understand

function sanitise(x) 
{ 
    if (!isNaN(x)) 
    { 
        return 'NaN'; // if you return NaN javascript treat as number  
    } 
    console.log(x)
    return x; 
} 
var input = '1'; 
console.log(typeof input); 
console.log(typeof sanitise(input), sanitise(input));
```